# Excel: copy cell' conditional formatting colour to all cells with same value

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-formatting

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD464.png)

The Aim: The image shows the “key” on the left, where cells will be coloured manually using mouse input.
A (red background)
B (green background)
C (blue background)
On the right, you see the "data" **where content-matching cells should be formatted to match their key** (as I've already done for representation purpose in the image)

Initial Situation: No cells are coloured or formatted in any way. The Excel spreadsheet has column A with certain values, And rest of the columns (C onwards) have the same/different values in a random manner (some cells even empty). Not all values in "key" area will be found in "Data" area or vice versa. No new data is being added in any area. User will only colour certain Values in "Key" area as per their wish.

Thus all “C” cells in the Data area should be coloured blue when "C" in Key area is coloured blue. Furthermore, if I change the formatting of “C” in the Key to have a purple background, all the “C” cells should switch from blue to purple. Also, if I add more to the Key (say, “D” with a yellow background) then any “D” cells should become yellow; if I remove a Key entry, then matching values in the Data area should revert to default styling.

I'm open to different trigger techniques,like manually running a macros via shortcut etc.
I suspect that if any of this is possible it will require VBA, but I’ve never used it so I’ve no idea where to start if that’s the case. The closest answer to my question was found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/472918/excel-conditionally-format-a-cell-using-the-format-of-another-content-matching/1633184?noredirect=1#comment2494641_1633184) but doesn't entirely work for me:

Answer (score 1):

First I though of using the Worksheet.Change event, by putting something like this into the worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim area As Range, c As Range
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then
    Set area = Range("B1:F20")
    For Each c In area
        If c.Value = Target.Value Then c.Interior.Color = Target.Interior.Color
    Next c
End If
End Sub
```

This is just a non-dynamic rough draft, but it "kind of" works.
Problem is that a change of color doesn't trigger the change event, funnily enough, changing the letter to the same letter – so no change at all – does trigger the event, as illustrated below:

[image]

We could use the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event instead, but then it wouldn't update until next time we selected the cell we want to update.

We could instead force it to update on next selection. Which isn't optimal either:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim reference As Range, refCell As Range, area As Range, areaCell As Range
Set reference = Range("A1:A3")      'Reference range
Set area = Range("B1:F20")          'Search range
    For Each refCell In reference   'Loop through the references
        For Each areaCell In area   'Loop through search range for each reference
            If areaCell.Value = refCell.Value Then areaCell.Interior.Color = refCell.Interior.Color
        Next areaCell
    Next refCell
End Sub
```

[image]

Obviously, using a button or similar to run the same code would also work, but I'm not entirely sure if we can make it run instantly.

To run it manually, put it as a normal sub in a module. (It still works in the sheet though).

```
Sub fillColor()
Dim reference As Range, area As Range, areaCell As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set reference = Range("A1")
Set area = Range("B1:E25")
        For Each areaCell In area
            If areaCell.Value = reference.Value Then
                areaCell.Interior.Color = reference.Interior.Color
                areaCell.Interior.Pattern = reference.Interior.Pattern
            End If
        Next areaCell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Still, you might want to add an option on what to to update, so it doesn't update it all.

Comment: Hey Christofer, Thank You for the prompt reply! Observations after applying both of your methods: 1. Since Key entries are 2500+ and data side has 30 columns (so 30 x 2500+ data); Method 2 freezes the sheet every time I colour a cell in key. 
2. Since code is checking every cell in data side, I guess its calculation heavy even on i7, 16GB ram
3. I put both these codes in the 'sheet' section in VBAProject-->Microsoft Excel Objects-->Sheet1. I hope that's the right place?

Comment: 4. Method 1 works as you demonstrated, & needs a cell edit trigger. Can we make an executable macros shortcut that user can input after they colour a cell?
5. Also in Method 1, if an already colour filled cell in key is changed to no-fill, all the same cells in data side switch to white colour-fill (instead of no-fill).

Comment: Yes, that is the correct place to put them. And yes, with large amounts of data, it can get very heavy, especially the second option, where absolutely everything gets calculated all the time, not very effective. You can call the macros from a button instead. Preferably put it in a module, and use like a regular sub. I can add some later.

Comment: No-fill doesn't seem to work with only using `interior.color`, but it will if you use `.Interior.Pattern` as well.

Comment: Ok This is where i would need some Primer level guidance. I added the code `c.Interior.Pattern = Target.Interior.Pattern` as a new line (in Mehots 1) after the color line. But that didn't seem to work. Debug said 'Next without For'. Secondly, debug says there's a syntax error in 6th line of the Normal Sub code you added. On removing the word 'reference' written after area, the code ran but sheet froze.

Comment: That's probably because of my one-line `If`. put the stuff after `then` on a new line, then the pattern on a thrid line, and then close the `If` with `End if` on the fourth line. And yeah, that must be some error when I copied it, that reference isn't supposed to bere there. But yeah, it's too many cells to go over. 30x2500 is probably not too bad, but then it's that times the `A` column. And if that is 2500 as well... we go from 75k to 187million. I tried using conditional formatting instead. But it's not fast enough to handle that many cells either. And  you end up with hundreds of rules.